# Invalid value for implementation data types

Tags: embedded, autosar

How to configure the Invalid Value for implementation data types (Especially for arrays, based on the size of the array we have to create that many array value specifications)??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a single `ImplementationDataType` of `category` ARRAY, you just create one `ArrayValueSpecification` that contains as many `NumericalValueSpecification`s as required.

Comment: I configured 3 NumericalValueSpecifications inside the ArrayValueSpecifications but in a generation which value I have to consider either first or all three of them values?

Comment: All three of them need to be considered.

Comment: I have one query, the generated invalid value macro will be like #define InvalidValue_<DataType>  {1,2,3} like this or any other form.{1,2,3} are the values specified in ArrayValueSpecification.